# How to load a Seq2Seq Model and use it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk, seq2seq

I have built a basic Chatbot using Seq2Seq model. The bot works great when I run the code in sequence in my notebook - i.e Build the model --> Train the model --> Test the model.

I now want to save the model after training, load the model and then test the model.

However, I am having issues / struggling to proceed further.

This is what I have got so far:

#### Save the model

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(sess, 'model_final.ckpt')
```

This seems to work ok

#### Load the model

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model_final.ckpt.meta")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
saver.restore(sess, "model_final.ckpt")
```

This seems to work ok

When I run in sequence, the below code does the work of taking the input question, tokenising it and responding to the question.

```
prediction_c  = tf.argmax(model_c, 2)
result_c = sess_c.run(prediction_c,
                  feed_dict={enc_input_c: input_batch_c,
                             dec_input_c: output_batch_c,
                             targets_c: target_batch_c})
```

Once I have loaded the Seq2Seq model, I am not sure how variables like model_c, input_c get values / initialized.

I do apologize for the basic nature of the question or if what I am trying to achieve makes no sense; I am just getting started on tensors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this?

Check lines 76-95 for restore code : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq_restore.py

The code used model.save and model.load to save and load the model respectively

The model that is being restored is : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py